# SwipeGesture on ImageView

Tags: uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer

I am working on an app (its actually a game) that needs to detect Swipe Gestures. When I do swipe on my image view, the image for the image view needs to be changed, but unfortunately it is not working as expected.

When I add the swipe gesture object to self.view, the desired action is performed whenever I swipe my finger to any location in the view, but I want this action to be performed only when I swipe my finger over the imageView.

On the other hand, when I try to add the swipe gesture to the image view, it doesn't respond to the gesture event.

Please reply if you have the solution to this problem!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like your UIImageView has **userInteractionEnabled** set to NO. Try setting yourImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES and adding your swipe gesture recognizer to the UIImageView.

Comment: Can you share more details about the situation? I've never had an issue with gesture recognizers working on UIImageViews - it sounds like there is something else in effect.

Answer (score 1):

I too faced the same issue.. 
The option 'User Interaction Enabled' under Attributes Inspector(available in Inspector window of Interface Builder) was unchecked,
Enabling it solved my problem.
done using storyboard...
Thanks